# how to handle two function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions `searching` and `searchhistory`. Currently these two function are running in my code but the value of `nbofimages` is not updated.

Also it's showing only one alert message after searchhistory function is completed.

```
$.when(searching(searchkwd, check_st, check_sf, '31', '1', filter, ori, colorcheck))
 .then(searchhistory(user_search,search_pars,search_username,nbofimages));

var nbofimages;

function searching(searchkwd, check_st, check_sf, '31', '1', filter, ori, colorcheck)
{
    nbofimages = "3";
    alert(nbofimages);
}

function searchhistory(user_search,search_pars,search_username,nbofimages)
{
    alert(nbofimages);
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? Arguments passed to `$.when` are expected to be promises, i.e. `searching` would have to return a promise. `.then` on the other hand expects a function reference, which is called once the promises are resolved. You are executing `searchhistory` immediately  and passing the return value to `.then`. What are you trying to accomplish? This [this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) about JavaScript debugging might help you.

Comment: [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) works with [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), but `searching` is not returning anything

Comment: No this is not my actual code.

Comment: So... how do you expect us to help you if you post different code? Minimal examples are ok, as long as they are "correct".

Answer (score 2):

Function passed to `$.when` requires a promise to be returned.

```
function searching(searchkwd, check_st, check_sf, '31', '1', filter, ori, colorcheck)
{
    nbofimages = "3";
    alert(nbofimages);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Even with this fix, the code still seems to be incorrect. `.then` should be passed a function reference.

Comment: @FelixKling, DO you mean anonymous functions, as the manual suggests?

Comment: It can be any function reference, but the OP is *calling* `searchhistory` and passes its return value to `.then`, which is currently `undefined`.

Comment: @Rohit: I believe your code just "works" because you are calling `searchhistory` after `search`. You could also do `search(); searchhistory();` to achieve the same. The code you posted does not show any need for `$.when` (are you actually aware of what it is doing?).

Comment: @FelixKling, How about `.then(function() { searchhistory(user_search,search_pars,search_username,nbofimages)); });`, will this be correct?